# What training to I need to craft potions and oils?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting, potions

I know that the Brew Potion feat can be used to make these items, but can I also use skills?

The [Paizo site](http://paizo.com/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html) states that potions can be crafted with the Brew Potion feat, Spellcraft skill, and Craft (alchemy) skill.

Does this mean I can just have Craft (alchemy) and not take the feat Brew Potion and still be able to make potions and oils?  Or do I still need the feat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://paizo.com/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html

> create magic items, spellcasters use special feats which allow them to
>   invest time and money in an item's creation. **At the end of this
>   process, the spellcaster must make a single skill check (usually
>   Spellcraft, but sometimes another skill) to finish the item**. If an
>   item type has multiple possible skills, you choose which skill to make
>   the check with. The DC to create a magic item is 5 + the caster level
>   for the item. Failing this check means that the item does not function
>   and the materials and time are wasted. Failing this check by 5 or more
>   results in a cursed item (see Cursed Items for more information).
>
> Note that all items have prerequisites in their descriptions. These
>   prerequisites must be met for the item to be created. Most of the
>   time, they take the form of spells that must be known by the item's
>   creator (although access through another magic item or spellcaster is
>   allowed). The DC to create a magic item increases by +5 for each
>   prerequisite the caster does not meet. **The only exception to this is
>   the requisite item creation feat, which is mandatory.** In addition,
>   you cannot create potions, spell-trigger, or spell-completion magic
>   items without meeting their spell prerequisites.

You can use *spellcraft* or *craft(alchemy)* for the final check to create the potion/oil, but the *brew potion* feat is still required.

Answer (score 5):

The link you cite doesn't quite say that. What the [Creating Potions section](http://paizo.com/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html#creating-potions) says is that *Brew Potion* is **required**, plus either *Spellcraft* or *Craft (alchemy)*. So yes, you still need the feat.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, you definitely need *Brew Potion* feat to create magical potions. However, I allowed non-magical alchemicals (including oil) to be created through craft(alchemy) skill in my game. You can see some examples of non-magical creations [here](http://paizo.com/prd/skills/craft.html), together with the Craft DC.

There is also a [calculator](http://viajon.net/pf/crafting/) that you might want to take a look at. It helps players and GMs keep track of crafting checks and you can see what you need to craft an alchemical item.

Comment: Magic oils are a specific term in Pathfinder and other d20 games, used for a fluid that can be smeared onto an object to put a spell effect on it like a potion, except it doesn't need someone able to drink it.